# Run a jar file only with jre

Tags: java, jar, environment-variables, command-prompt

I am having jre7. I am not having jdk. I want to run a jar file using that.

I have set jre_home to the jre7 folder and path environment variable is also set to same value.
When I try to run jar file i get the error-
**Java is not recognized as internal or external command.**

what is the solution to this? Should I set path variable to jre7/bin ?

Comment: Yes you have to add the `bin` Folder to the path

Comment: Forget about the jre_home environment variable. It is not used by Java. You must make sure that the `bin` directory of the JRE is in your PATH.